# Parsing age string with awk

Tags: awk, kubernetes

I need to parse out the age of a pod for a Kubernetes/OpenShift monitoring script.

I need to compare the age of the pod and notify about pods in a certain state for a long amount of time. The age of pods is displayed as 1d - for one day, 1h - one hour, 10m - ten minutes or 5s - five seconds, for example. In practice it could be something like 1d5m24s.

My question is how does one best parse out and compare the age of pods? I've tried with the date utility from inside awk and it doesn't actually parse strings like this. Is there any good way to do this in awk?

Some example output of what I'm parsing:

```
NAME                                                    READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
testpod-4e8e492d                                        0/1       Error       0          30h
another-testpod-d1ed34d7                                0/1       Error       0          31h
```

Comment: `30h` and `31h` aren't good test cases if the field could be `1d5m24s`. Please [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input and add the expected output given that input. Also define `a long amount of time` and explain how that value fits into your expectations for this script.

Comment: In the command you're running to get the pod age info, are there any options to format the age differently, for example in seconds (e.g., `86724s` instead of `1d5m24s`)?  Or perhaps to give the timestamp of the pod's start time in seconds since 1/1/1970, which your script can compare with the current timestamp (from `date -d now +%s`) to find the age?  The less parsing of complex strings your monitoring script performs, the more reliable it will be.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you actually want to do as a result of the calculation so here's a GNU awk (for the 4th arg to `split()`) script that will just print the seconds for each timestamp, assuming we don't have to consider DST and/or leap seconds:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    mult["s"] = m = 1
    mult["m"] = m *= 60
    mult["h"] = m *= 60
    mult["d"] = m *= 24
}
NR == 1 {
    secs = "SECS"
}
NR > 1 {
    secs = 0
    n = split($NF,number,/[[:alpha:]]/,denomination)
    for ( i=1; i < n; i++ ) {
        secs += number[i] * mult[denomination[i]]
    }
}
{
    print $0, secs
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NAME                                                    READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE    SECS
testpod-4e8e492d                                        0/1       Error       0          30h    108000
another-testpod-d1ed34d7                                0/1       Error       0          31h    111600
another-testpod-d1ed34d7                                0/1       Error       0          1d5m24s    86724
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
NAME                                                    READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
testpod-4e8e492d                                        0/1       Error       0          30h
another-testpod-d1ed34d7                                0/1       Error       0          31h
another-testpod-d1ed34d7                                0/1       Error       0          1d5m24s
```

If you don't have GNU awk you can do this with any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    mult["s"] = m = 1
    mult["m"] = m *= 60
    mult["h"] = m *= 60
    mult["d"] = m *= 24
}
NR == 1 {
    secs = "SECS"
}
NR>1 {
    secs = 0
    time = $NF
    while ( match(time,/[^0-9]/) ) {
        secs += substr(time,1,RSTART-1) * mult[substr(time,RSTART,1)]
        time = substr(time,RSTART+1)
    }
}
{
    print $0, secs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a common timestamp format for [date](/questions/tagged/date). We have to parse it manually. It's pretty straightforward with a (relatively) simple (but repetitive) regular expression.

Using GNU awk:

```bash
for ts in 2d34h4m56s 2d 34h 4m 56s 34h4m; do
  echo "$ts" | gawk '
    match($1, "(([0-9]+)d)?(([0-9]+)h)?(([0-9]+)m)?(([0-9]+)s)?", m) {
      printf "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds\n", m[2], m[4], m[6], m[8]
    }
  '
done
```

```
2 days, 34 hours, 4 minutes, 56 seconds
2 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
0 days, 34 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
0 days, 0 hours, 4 minutes, 0 seconds
0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 56 seconds
0 days, 34 hours, 4 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, that duration format is actually recognised by ast-open's time parsing routines including the `%T` or `ksh93`'s `printf` builtin (as well as the [standard ISO8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) which are similar to that).

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%(%s)T\n" "#0 1d5m24s"'
86724
```

(here adding that duration to epoch seconds 0 (`#0`) to get a number of seconds).

So in `ksh93`, you could do:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
(( threshold = 12 * 60 * 60 )) # 12 hours for instance
{
  read -rA headers
  while read -r "${headers[@]}" rest; do
    seconds=${ printf '%(%s)T' "#0 $AGE"; }
    if (( seconds > threshold )); then
      print -r -- "$NAME is over 12 hours old"
    fi
  done
} < that-file
```

That's also the format used by its `printf`'s `%Q` directive though how much precision you get is a bit arbitrary (only two components):

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%Q\n" 123456'
1d10h
```